# Is there a substitute for tamari and soy as I have a soya allergy?

Tags: substitutions, soy

I'm on an exclusion diet for some time. I have found loads of amazing recipes that have soy or tamari or miso paste in them but I can't eat these. Does anyone know of something that's similar?

Comment: related (but also requires vegan) : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1753/67

Answer (score 4):

There are actually products that are [Soy Free Soy Sauce](http://www.vitacost.com/coconut-secret-coconut-aminos-soy-free-seasoning-sauce-8-fl-oz-12?csrc=GPF-PA-Food%20%26%20Beverages-851492002047&ci_gpa=pla&ci_kw=&ci_src=17588969&ci_sku=851492002047&gclid=Cj0KEQiAu_GmBRDhtK-kzqKcuJwBEiQAJvB8n6fTMnEjK_OTIkRS-re1fvlbMn0UEabLDpqduuK0WTwaAk2m8P8HAQ). You can also find recipes to make your own. This [Recipe for Soy Free Soy Sauce Substitute](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/soy-sauce-substitute/) has great reviews and sounds pretty good. It is made with bouillon, molasses, balsamic vinegar and seasonings.

A lot of people swear by [Bragg Liquid Aminos](http://www.iherb.com/Bragg-Liquid-Aminos-Natural-Soy-Sauce-Alternative-16-fl-oz-473-ml/38027?gclid=Cj0KEQiAu_GmBRDhtK-kzqKcuJwBEiQAJvB8n1Uw4LtPbADWI4ZMalTo0zgDAPOwKZDuZsaUjZHpQZsaAprV8P8HAQ) as a soy free soy sauce alternative, but it actually contains soy.

There are chickpea or adzuli bean soy-free miso pastes from [South River Miso Company](http://www.southrivermiso.com/store/p/8-Chickpea-Barley.html). [Miso Master](https://great-eastern-sun.com/stuff/miso-master-organic-kosher-soy-free-chickpea-miso-) makes a chickpea one too.

You can also ferment your own chickpea miso, but it takes about a year. There are instructions in [The Art of Fermentation](http://www.thekitchn.com/the-art-of-fermentation-by-sandor-ellix-katz-174374) by Sandor Ellix Katz.

Comment: Bragg's aminos is definitely soy, but there is a brand of coconut aminos available that is soy free.

Comment: @sourd'oh That's the first one I listed, it's the only one I could find.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest substitute would be salt and beef boulion. It's not exactly the same but it imparts the basic flavors (salt and umami). Depending on how salty, you may not even need to add salt to the beef tea.

Answer (score 0):

Both Maggi and Bragg's are made from soy, so don't use them.

The closest things that I can think of Worstershire sauce or fish sauce ... both give salt, but also bring other qualities that might not be desired.  Fish sauce in particular has a much stronger flavor that can overwhelm dishes in large quantities.

Another common replacement is black bean pase thinned with water, but every recipe that I've found suggests that one of the ingredients in it is soy sauce.  (I don't know if they're all copying from the same recipe, so it might be possible that there are commercially made ones out there without it)